# Excel pivot table, filtering formula-based values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Here's the issue I'm facing:

[image]

Table 2 is raw data. Table 1 fetches data from Table 2 with formulas as can be seen from the image. The pivot table uses Table 1 as source data, and you can instantly see the problem - pivot table considers all cells in Table 1 to have values (formulas), while I'd like it to count only cells that have an actual value ("Y").

How can I tell the pivot table to filter values to count only "Y"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in pivot, but if you can change your formula in Table2 to `=IF(M5="";"";1)` then in pivot you can use `SUM` or `Count numbers` functions to get correct result.

[image]